# How to check ready state for Firefox using RFT

Tags: automation, rft

I have been working on a web app, and it was designed for Firefox only.
The getProperty(".readyState") always return 4 >> READY even if the page is still loading.
I already tried the following:
- image comparison using Robot (NO LUCK)
- waitForExistence

readyState is an IE property and it seems it is not working properly using Firefox.

any help from the experts are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Try using `waitForExistence` on some object on the page that signifies that it is ready. That is, rather than `waitForExistence` on the page itself, `waitForExistence` on a child object of that page. For example, if a certain link or button is only available when the page is ready, sync on that.
- If this is a page with asynchronous requests running in the background, RFT does have functions which allow you to sync on completion of ajax requests. See the [RFT online help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/c_ajax_support.html) docs for ajax support.